# DAX - check for the existance of a column in the query

Tags: dax, tabular, ssas-tabular, ssas-2016

Is it possible, in a DAX measure, to check if the current query contains a particular column?

For example, I have a column named "Time" - is it possible to detect if a user in a self service environment has included this in their report, from the measure?

Edit - adding example of an output

An example output would be below

```
+---------+---------+------+--------------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   | Col3 | ContainsCol3 |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 |  123 | True         |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+

+---------+---------+------+--------------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   | Col4 | ContainsCol3 |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 |  123 | False        |
+---------+---------+------+--------------+
```

The query containing Col3 returns true, the query that does not include col3 returns false.

Comment: What exactly is the use case?

Comment: @FoxanNg conditionally summing a different source column depending on the column used from the time dimension

Comment: is it only if the column is included on the rows/columns of the query/pivot?

Comment: might help to post some sample (pseudo) code to help give a clearer picture

Comment: @BillAnton see edit. I hope that makes sense, it's not easy to draw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not exactly, but you can use functions like ISCROSSFILTERED, ISFILTERED, HASONEFILTER, HASONEVALUE which might be sufficient depending on your end-goal.

Comment: Unfortunately, my end goal is a bit of a hack to switch out the underlying column of a measure if a certain dimension column is included. ISCROSSFILTERED sounds like it may get me close, but in all likelihood there wouldn't be a filter on the column and therefore I might not be able to detect it.